# measurable set where limit of functions exists

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f_n :X\to [-\infty,+\infty]$ be measurable functions. Is $
E = \{ x\ \vert \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n (x) \text{ exists}\}
$ measurable?

Comment: Hint $E=\{x: \limsup_nf_n(x) = \liminf_nf_n(x)\}$

Comment: $$E=\{x| \limsup_nf_{n\to\infty}(x) = \liminf_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)\}.$$ 
So $\limsup \limits_{n\to \infty}f_n$ and $\liminf \limits_{n\to\infty} f_n$ are also measurable. Then $\{\limsup\limits_{n\to \infty}f_n > \liminf\limits_{n\to \infty}\}f_n$ is measurable. So $$ E= \{x|\exists \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n \backslash \{\limsup_{n\to \infty}f_n > \liminf_{n\to \infty}f_n\}$$ is measurable ?